# firebase functions:shell onWrite property undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to test my cloud functions locally. I am using the command `firebase functions:shell` which starts the emulator successfully. I have the following cloud function in my `index.ts`:

```
export const stripeCharge = functions.region('europe-west1').database
    .ref('/payments/{userId}/{paymentId}')
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
        someCode;
});
```

I read that you should invoke an onWrite firestore function the following way (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell):

```
stripeCharge({before: "oldData", after: "newData"})
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
'Successfully invoked function.'
firebase > !  TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventType' of undefined
    at cloudFunction (C:\Users\Jesper\intergun\functions\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\cloud-functions.js:80:40)
    at Run (C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.16.0\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:458:20)
    at C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.16.0\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:442:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.16.0\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.16.0\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:3:12)
    at Run (C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.16.0\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:435:12)
    at C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.16.0\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:457:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
!  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

The error happens in some other file and I'm not sure why. What am I missing?

Edit: My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^2.5.0",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^7.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "^8.0.1",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
    "sharp": "^0.22.1",
    "stripe": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/sharp": "^0.22.2",
    "@types/stripe": "^6.30.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: which version of node are u using?

Comment: @andresmijares Hi, thanks for trying to help. `node --version` prints `8.16.0`. Is that a problem?

Comment: maybe, your functions is complaining about the `context`, in your case, it is triggering a legacy one, try updating ur dependencies and make sure ur package.json, list the right version of node

Comment: the last thing I would check, are u running `npm run build` before running `firebase functions:shell` ??? so we can discard a transpile problem

Comment: @andresmijares I have updated my question with my `package.json` file. Do you see any problems there? Also, I ran `npm update`, but it seems like it only updated typescript. Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: @andresmijares I just tried running `npm run build` before `firebase functions:shell`, but the result is the same... :-(

Comment: I have the same problem. I cannot run functions locally when working with the RTDB.

Answer (score 2):

After replicating this I've found [this thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1288) it looks there is an open case for this issue.

The similar setup works fine for Firestore, but the issue seems to to be with the RTDB, I assume we have to wait until they solve it, sorry :(

Comment: Damn, that's annoying. Are you sure it's the same issue though? I checked your link and the `eventType` property in the `context` object is not undefined in his case, which seems to be the problem for me.

Comment: It very likely, inreplicate thé issue and also tried with firestore and worked as expected

Comment: I can also replicate this, sadly cannot test my RTDB functions in the shell